# Python constraint inverse

Tags: python, constraints

I am looking for a solution to use the numbers 2,3,4,5 for 10 times to get an exact sum of 40; so I have written the following code

```
from constraint import Problem, InSetConstraint, ExactSumConstraint
problem = Problem()
problem.addVariables(range(10), range(10))
problem.addConstraint(InSetConstraint([2,3,4,5]))
problem.addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(40))
solutions = problem.getSolutions()
print(solutions)
```

which works well, but what I want is the other way around to limit the result meaning my variables should be [2,3,4,5] & they have a value equals to how many times each is used, I am unable to figure out how it works I have tried the following

```
from constraint import Problem, ExactSumConstraint
problem = Problem()
problem.addVariables([2,3,4,5], [1,1,1,1])
problem.addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(10))
solutions = problem.getSolutions()
print(solutions)
```

How can I get it to multiply the key by value & where to add the constraint of 40 here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, using the following code:

```
from constraint import Problem, ExactSumConstraint
problem = Problem()
MaximumSum = 10
MaxMultiplicationSum = 40
Variables = ("a", "b", "c", "d")
realKeys = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 5}
for Variable in Variables:
    problem.addVariable(Variable, range(1, MaximumSum - len(Variables)))
problem.addConstraint(ExactSumConstraint(MaximumSum), Variables)
problem.addConstraint(lambda a,b,c,d: 2 * a + 3 * b + 4 * c + 5 * d == MaxMultiplicationSum)
solutions = problem.getSolutions()
for solution in solutions:
    print(dict((realKeys[key], value) for (key, value) in solution.items()))
```